# webpack - specifying require order

Tags: angularjs, webpack

For an angular application, I am building a Dll of my vendor libraries. I am having a problem where the core library (`snapjs`) has not been loaded by the time the angular-wrapper (`angular-snap`) is loaded.

What I see in the `vendor.bundle.js` is happening is that the `angular-snap` library is being loaded first, therefore `window.Snap` is not defined (since `Snap` is located further down the `vendor.bundle.js` file).

If I manually move the `Snap` library above the `angular-snap` library, everything works.

Is there a way to specify require order in order for this to not happen?